# How to delete lines that end with an element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Pyhton pandas :

A quick question I have a dataframe containing email addresses named

adress_id :

j.k@hotmail.com

s.r@gmail.com

f.g@apple.com

s.k@gmail.com

I would like to remove all the lines that contain that end with "@gmail.com" to have ideally this:

adress_id

j.k@hotmail.com

f.g@apple.com
how can i proceed ?

ps : sorry I couldn't make a chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY:

```
df = df[~df.adress_id.str.endswith('@gmail.com')]
```

OUTPUT:

```
         adress_id
0  j.k@hotmail.com
2    f.g@apple.com
```

Comment: btw, fun is dupe same substring ;)

Answer (score 2):

Something as simple as this should do

```
>>> df.query('address_id.str.contains("@gmail.com")')
```

Comment: I know less query but it works too thank you very much for the tips